# Should you avoid Guavas Ordering.usingToString()?

Tags: java, guava, effective-java

This question was prompted after reading Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java". Specifically in Item #10, he argues that it is bad practice to parse an object's string representation and use it for anything except a friendlier printout/debug. The reason is that such a use "is error-prone, results in fragile systems that break if you change the format".
To me it looks like Guava's [`Ordering.usingToString()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#usingToString%28%29) is a spot on example of this. So is it bad practice to use it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, if the sorting is only used for deciding in which order to display things to a user, I'd argue it's part of "friendlier printout/debug".

If, however, your codes correctness depends on the ordering, then I'd argue that it's indeed a bad idea to depend on `toString`.

Answer (score 3):

As the author of that method, I would agree: it's really just a crutch. For those "look, I just need an `Ordering<Object>`, dammit" cases. It should probably be removed, since you can get its behavior with `Ordering.onResultOf(Functions.toStringFunction)` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

*If* your program ever used the `toString()` for lexical sorting using natural ordering in such a way that program execution depends on it, then it would be wise to override the default `toString()` of the class that extended. You should in that case make the `toString()` method final *and clearly document* that it is used for ordering.

It would however be much better to create another method returning a `String` and create an ordering depending on that result, possibly by creating a specific `Comparator` to do the sorting. See for instance the final method [`name()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name%28%29) used for enumerations in Java. In general it creates the same String as [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString%28%29) but it is still possible to perform ordering with it even if `toString()` has been overridden.

If you use the last method, then the `Ordering.usingToString()` would not be of much use of course.

Answer (score 0):

There are some obvious cases where it actually makes sense like StringBuffer etc. Obviously it doesn't make sense for most "business" classes to depend on toString().